# Adding to collection before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to do something like this:

```
event = Event.new
loc = Location.new
loc.name = "test"
loc.save
event.locations << loc
event.save!
```

Where event and location have a many to many relationship. However, I keep getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Event locations is invalid
```

This works fine if I save event first, however I do not have that option in the context that I am working in.

Here are my models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  #belongs_to :user
  has_many :event_locations
  has_many :locations, :through => :event_locations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end

class EventLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :location

  validates_presence_of :event
  validates_presence_of :location

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_locations
  has_many :events, :through => :event_locations
end
```

Now I figured out that the validations on the join model EventLocation cause this problem.

Should I not validate this? Is there a different way it's done?

Comment: Calling `event.locations << loc` will call `save` on `loc` implicitly, so you dont need to do it yourself beforehand.  But can you paste your models, as we need that info to answer your question.  You have validation failures, but without seeing your validations we cant answer fully

Comment: figured it out! thanks to your ideas :). however, its because of validates_presence_of :event
  validates_presence_of :location in event_locations. don't i need these validations there?

Comment: you should always work on relations like `event.locations.build` or `event.locations.create` so that rails can take care of the object management.

Comment: in my actual code i was using existing location objects so i couldn't use build or create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Try either a)

```
class EventLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :location

  validates_presence_of :event_id
  validates_presence_of :location_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

or - if you don't need `EventLocation` for anything else - b)

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  #belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

**What's going on?**

In your 'collision' model `EventLocation` you validate presence of both `:location` and `:event` which causes your problem.

To understand why this is happening and how to address it, we need to first understand how the validation system works and what adding a model to a `:through`-collection does.

**Validation**

In this particular case we `validate_presence_of` something and that tells the model to look at that something and see if it's present.

Simplified:

```
validates_presence_of :something
```

when saving, leads to

```
model.save if model.something.present?
```

So this *should* be checking the right thing.

**What about `:through`-collections**

Since the above obviously doesn't work the way expected, we can infer that

```
event.locations << loc
```

does not actually set

```
EventLocation.new(location: loc)
```

So what really might happen is, that rails 'just' sets the IDs like

```
EventLocation.new(location_id: loc.id)
```

**What does that mean?**

Assuming the above is correct, validating presence of the ids instead of the associated objects might do the trick here.

**Why bother?**

Of course, validations are generally not a bad idea, but there might be an alternative here and that is `has_and_belongs_to_many`. That methods has a lot of magic packed into it, which equips the models to deal with a collision table that doesn't need a model attached to it.

Generally speaking, if you don't **really** need to attach any business logic or additional data to the collision of two tables, rely on the magic built-in (habtm) to do the right thing for you, instead of doing (and validating) it manually.